# How does solution of least square analysis change if the output of datapoint is increased by a constant?

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, weighted-regression

What will be the effect on the solution of least square analysis if we apply the following transformations on the training set:  add a real number $k$ to the output value of each datapoint.

[image: phi]

[image: y]

And the model is $y = \phi w$ where $w$ is the weight attached to the functions $\phi_1, \phi_2, \phi_3....\phi_p$.

Least square analysis gives the solution for $w$ as $$w = (\phi^T \phi)^{-1}\phi^Ty$$

Now all the $y_i$'s are increased by $k$. So the vector $y$ becomes $y+K$ where $K$ is a $m \times 1$ vector with all components as $k$.
Hence the new solution becomes
$$w_{f} = (\phi^T \phi)^{-1}\phi^T(y+K)$$ which simplifies to $$w_f = w + (\phi^T \phi)^{-1}\phi^TK$$

But another line of thought is that if the original line was $y = mx+c$, then as the data points are shifted up by a distance $k$ only the $c$ should change to $c+k$. And in the weighted model, only the weight attached to the constant function should increase by $k$. That is,
$$w_0^{new} = w_0 + k$$ 
So my question is how does the matrix analysis give the same answer as the graphical analysis? I understand for that $(\phi^T \phi)^{-1}\phi^TK$ should evaluate to a column matrix with only the first component as $k$ and rest all zeros. But I can't figure out how this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively because $K$ is a vector of equal constants then $w_{K}=(\phi^T\phi)^{-1}\phi^TK$ is a solution to the model for $y^*=K$. That is, $w_{K}=K$ (we get ideal prediction for this constant model because e=y^*-K=0), so we get $w_{F}=w+K$. So the main idea is to divide the problem into two problems where the second is separate squares deviation minimization under independent variable equals K and the solution to this problem is evidently $y^*=K$ as deviation will be zero.

Comment: A potential editor suggested that this answer should read "... that is $w_{K}$ *is a vector with the first component as $k$ and the rest being zeros* (we get ...".

Comment: I don't really understand what you are saying. Is your intuition same as the second approach I have used?

Comment: And my question is, how can the matrix approach be used to get the same result?

Comment: Not exactly. You have shown that $w_{f}=w+(\phi^T\phi)^{-1}\phi^TK$. But $(\phi^T\phi)^{-1}\phi^TK$ is a solution to a problem where dependend variable is K and as it is a constant vector then LS solution to it will be also K. It means that $w_{f}=w+K$. It easer then to proof that $(\phi^T\phi)^{-1}\phi^TK=K$ where $K=(k...k)^T$ as what I am say is automatically evidient from square errors minimization point of view.